# Raster overlay on sf object

Tags: raster, r, sf

Question: why does a raster object plot over an object of class "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" but incorrectly over an object of class "sf"?

I am working with this [raster](http://lucid.wur.nl/storage/downloads/high-carbon-ecosystems/GEOCARBON_Forest_AGB_Map.zip). I'd like to overlay it on a map of Russia.

I'd like to use the graticule function in plot_sf, so I need to plot an sf object:

```
library(maptools)
library(sf)
library(raster)
# define CRS
crs.laea <- CRS("+proj=laea +lat_0=56 +lon_0=100
               +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 
             +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
# load in raster
    agb<-raster(".../GEOCARBON_Forest_AGB_Map/GEOCARBON_AGB_Map.tif")
    #crop to desired area
    boreal<-crop(agb, extent(0, 180, 30, 80))
    russia_la<-projectRaster(boreal,crs=crs.laea)
# load in background map
    data("wrld_simpl", package = "maptools")                                                                            
    wm <- crop(wrld_simpl, extent(0, 180, 30, 80)) 
    wm <- spTransform(wm, CRSobj = crs.laea)  
    sf_worldmap<-st_as_sf(wm)
```

I now make a nice background plot:

```
plot(sf_worldmap[1], axes=T,key.pos=NULL,
     border="darkgrey", col="lightgrey",
     xlim=c(-3660660,st_bbox(sf_worldmap[1])[c(3)]-3000000),
     ylim=c(-1000000,ymax(russia_la)-1000000),
     graticule=st_crs("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"),
     lon= seq(20, 140, by = 20),
     lat=seq(40,60,by=10))
```

[image]

Then I go to add the raster, and it does not plot properly:

```
plot(russia_la, axes=F,key.pos=NULL, add=TRUE,
 xlim=c(-3660660,st_bbox(inline[1])[c(3)]-3000000),
 ylim=c(-1000000,ymax(russia_la)-1000000))
```

This is the resulting plot. (A similar image results from `plot(russia_la,add=TRUE)`, but is not shown here for brevity.)
[image]

The same problem does not occur if I plot the raster over the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, but as I noted earlier I want to use the graticule feature and that is only available with sf objects.

```
plot(wm, border="darkgrey", col="lightgrey", axes=F, 
          xlim=c(-3660660,xmax(russia_la)),
          ylim=c(-1000000,ymax(russia_la)-1000000))
plot(russia_la,add=T)
```

[image]

Comment: You also have to apply your limits to the *russia_la* dataset, it does not collect hem from the plot before. If you plot your worldmap without your bounding box and then add the other raster on top it will fit perfectly.

Comment: @Illundra I did try that, I think.  I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Is there a way you can provide your data? Would be easier to try it out like this

Comment: The zip file with the raster is linked in the question. You can also download from http://lucid.wur.nl/datasets/high-carbon-ecosystems (it is the GEOCARBON global forest biomass dataset)

Comment: I can not explain you why it distorts the data when only using plot(sf_worldmap[1]) - I always thought this should work too. Anyhow, if you use plot(st_geometry(sf_worldmap)) with all your settings it does work.

Comment: That worked, thank you!!